# Add an image box besides featured image?

Tags: posts, images

When you want to associate an image to a post which already has its own featured image, you have to use a custom field : you upload an image just as if you wanted to add an image inside your post, but then you just copy the image URL, click cancel, and put the image URL in the custom field value : burdensome.

Is it possible to do that automatically without any need to copy and paste any URL, like having another featured image, but with a specific name and having the properties of a custom field ?

I hope my question is understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add 2nd featured image using [Multiple Post Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/installation/) plugin, make sure to follow the installation instruction.

Comment: Does this plugin create all the images sizes defined for the original featured image?

Comment: take a look at the screenshot http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/screenshots/, it's using default wp media uploader. So all behaviours are the same as the original.